# pointers messing with my values

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on this school project, which draws two bunnies and you should be able to see through one of them. Please note that the whole code is just a template made by the teachers and we are supposed to fill it in with our own code.
So I've got a loop which goes through all the pixels and instead of drawing then immediately we're supposed to store them in a Head and a Node Buffer.
The HeadBuffer only stores indexes which are later used when accessing the NodeBuffer.

see here: http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/06/2041_final.pdf

An my problem is not being able to retreat the value correctly right after storing it when filling the buffers, so i cant access it properly to sort it, blend the colors and write out.

Written in C

declared:

```
//in student.c
local:
    int Q;
global:
    S_Frag fragmentIn;
    S_Frag *fragmentOut;
    int *ext;
    int index;
//up to here
```

.

```
typedef struct S_Vector
{
   int     size;           
   int     reserved;       
   int     elemSize;       
   char    * data;         
} S_Vector;

typedef struct S_Frag
{
    S_RGBA      color;      
    double      depth;      
    int         next;       
} S_Frag;

//returns pointer to the i-th element
IZG_INLINE void * vecGetPtr(S_Vector *pVec, int i)
{
    IZG_ASSERT(pVec && i < pVec->size);
    return pVec->data + i * pVec->elemSize;
}

IZG_INLINE S_Frag makeFrag(S_RGBA color, double depth, int next)
{
    S_Frag frag;
    frag.color = color;
    frag.depth = depth;
    frag.next = next;
    return frag;
}

//appends pElem to the end of S_Vector, returns index of new pElem
int vecPushBack(S_Vector *pVec, void *pElem);

//sets the i-th elem. of pVec to pElem
IZG_INLINE void vecSet(S_Vector *pVec, int i, void * pElem)
{
    IZG_ASSERT(pVec && i < pVec->size && pElem);
    MEMCOPY(pVec->data + i * pVec->elemSize, pElem, pVec->elemSize);
}
```

.

```
//student.c
Q = x + y*globWidth;  //make 2 dimensional array 1 dimensional

ext = (int *) vecGetPtr(HeadBuffer, Q); //get index that was in headBuffer

fragmentIn = makeFrag(color, z, *ext); //put it in a new fragment

index = vecPushBack(NodeBuffer, &fragmentIn);//put new frag. in nodebuffer

vecSet(HeadBuffer, Q, &index);//update index in headbuffer

//here comes the messed up part
fragmentOut = (S_Frag *) vecGetPtr(NodeBuffer, index);
printf("::%d\n", fragmentOut->next);

// expected: -1 or 435 or 46 or 1120
// gotten: -8503629141
```

also the gotten value changes when i let the loop run and print it like this, but still something huge

Headbuffer is initialized to hold sizeof(int) and to hold width*heigth(of the window) of those, each element is -1 in the beginning

Nodebuffer is just set to hold elements of sizeof(S_Frag) and vecPushBack() manages the memory stuff for me

when i try to printf() *ext, index, Q, fragmentIn.next everything looks just fine

if you can tell the mistake, I would be so grateful, thanks

oh and btw i can't change anything else but my student.c file

EDIT: i also tried getting the depth out from a fragment using

```
printf("::%f\n", fragmentOut->depth);
```

and there were some 0's , -0.00000 to be specific along with numbers like -1523...25 zeros...0.00000 in the output

Comment: `vecGetPtr()` returns a void pointer that is casted to `S_Frag*`. That is not a problem as long as `NodeBuffer` is a vector of `S_Frag`... How do you ensure that it is the case ?

Comment: when the renderer is called there is a function that initializes everything and part of it: NodeBuffer = vecCreateEmpty(sizeof(S_Frag ));

Comment: in the makefrag function, it is trying to return a complete struct.  That is NOT good practice.  Much better to malloc a struct, fill in the struct fields, then return a pointer to the struct.

Comment: 'typedef'ing a struct is a bad idea.  It clutters the code, can be (and often is) mis-leading, and clutters the compiler name space.

Comment: when creating a linked list of structs, the 'next' field should be a pointer to the struct type, NOT an integer.

Comment: well like I said, we are only allowed to change the student.c file, because that's the way they're gonna compile it, nothing I can do about it, but I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: there is not enough information in the student.c file.  please post the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've just figured it out, of course it's me making mistakes and not double checking... there's another function that clears the buffers and I thought it clears them not that often, but in fact it clears them VERY often and that caused all the mess :D

Thanks for your time anyway, solved

Comment: Please never use bad language here.